How can I encode Tooltip in Chart.js?
hello I'm the beginner of making a webpage. I just used the template which I downloaded at Internet and changed a little.
Actually I'm Korean. so I used korean at my pages. but only the tooltip part was garbled.
enter image description here
Here is my PieChart.js. and I'm also using .net core MVC.
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["전체 수량", "완료량"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [116, 256],
            backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a'/*, '#36b9cc'*/],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673'/*, '#2c9faf'*/],
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
        }],
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            titleFontFamily: "'맑은 고딕', 'Arial', sans-serif",
            bodyFontFamily: "'맑은 고딕', 'Arial', sans-serif",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
            bodyFontColor: "#858796",
            borderColor: '#dddfeb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            xPadding: 15,
            yPadding: 15,
            displayColors: false,
            caretPadding: 10,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index] || '';

                    var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

                    return label+': ' +value+ '개' 
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        cutoutPercentage: 80,
    },
});

1.I tried to put this tag in HTML file.
<meta charset="utf-8" />

and also  change the font that is suitable for korean language.

options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            titleFontFamily: "'맑은 고딕', 'Arial', sans-serif",
            bodyFontFamily: "'맑은 고딕', 'Arial', sans-serif",


Please create a Test Page, and using my test code. In this test page, it contains html,head... tags. It works in my side.

Please let us know, by editing your post, what version of chart.js are you using. The options.tooltips type of option is specific to old version 2. Do you need to use such an old version? If not, start using the latest version (4+), for which the tooltip options are defined in options.plugin.tooltip.

@JasonPan! Thank you for your help! I tested your code and it Worked! I'll try this to use on my code.

@kikon  I used Chart.js v2.9.4 because I used a template that I downloaded on Internet. I should upgrade the version as you mentioned. Thanks!
